# SQL: How to get last date in groupby for getting unique records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a data where I have to use multiple joins and figures out that one of the table is producing duplicates as I applied Group by on dates as well and b/c of different dates my query takes in duplicate values.

I wrote following query

```
SELECT 
ll.ID,
ll.EST_DT
gg.col1 ,
ll.EST_CLAIM_DT,
gg.col2

FROM table gg 

inner join 
(select substr(ID,1,instr(ID,'-',7)-1) EST_ID, 
max(est_dt) as EST_DT, 
max(EST_CLAIM_DT) as EST_CLAIM_DT 
from table group by substr(gg.ID,1,instr(ID,'-',7)-1)) ll

on substr(ID,1,instr(gg.ID,'-',7)-1)=substr(ll.ID,1,instr(ll.ID,'-',7)-1)
GROUP BY
ll.ID,
ll.EST_DT
gg.col1 ,
ll.EST_CLAIM_DT,
gg.col2
```

Table looks like this:

```
+-----------------+------------+----------------+------+------+
|       ID        |  est_date  | est_claimed_dt | col1 | col2 |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+------+------+
| EST-U-1040452-1 | 28/02/2019 | 28/02/2019     |   50 |   50 |
| EST-U-1040452-2 | 5/10/2020  | 5/10/2020      |   50 |   50 |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+------+------+
```

Desired output

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+------+------+
|   ID    | est_date  | est_claimed_dt | col1 | col2 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+------+------+
| 1040452 | 5/10/2020 | 5/10/2020      |   50 |   50 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+------+------+
```

I get this error as well

> Negative sub string length not allowed

P.S. I have search SO for this issue and it helped but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Looks like you should also apply the `substr(...)` on `ll.ID` in your main query. The negative substring length is maybe occurring because you have values without "-" in the string? In that case the `instr()` will give 0, minus 1 equals -1 (which is not allowed).

Comment: @Martin, I did that too, still was giving this error. that's why I turned to some help, not getting my head around it :)

Comment: Maybe first split the query in 2 parts: main and sub. Check if you have duplicates/errors in main query. Check if you have duplicates/errors in subquery. Only then combine them.

Comment: You may be looking for substring_index.

Comment: Do not parse the date via string functions, use STR_TO_DATE().